# User Module issue

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

for one of my sites I'm using the module "Plus User Panel".

This modules displays a login and once logged in, a user panel or user menu.
It works in the sense, that it uses the 'Menu module' for my User Menu and it's menu items.

If I change the menu items for my user menu, it does also change the menu option for the user panel module obviously. And if I change the Title of the Menu Module linked to my User Menu, it is "supposed" to change the title of the Plus User Panel as well.

Here I am getting an issue which I can't understand why.

The Plus User Panel will only display the Menu items from my User Menu IF it's Menu Module is named "User Menu". If I change the name of the Menu module to anything else, the menu items get hidden and I only see the log out button.

Tried to delete and re-install the module and re-create my User menu and all, but still the same, can't change the title of the module 'plus user panel' to anything else but User Menu, where I want it to changed to "Brúkara Meny".

I'm using this module for two of my sites, and it works perfectly on my other website, without any troubles. But for some reason not this one

Then tried to see if I could just go into the module's code and change it, but without luck.

This is the file that shows the user menu:

[default.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9sv6r13wwf9nd7/default.php?dl=0)

The html output is:

```
<div id="plusl-content">
   <div id="plusl-content-profile" class="plusl-content-block" style="right: 69.9166px; top: 695.167px; display: block;">
      <div id="module-in-profile">
         <div class="moduletable">
             <h3>User Menu</h3> // This is the title of the Menu Module //
         <ul class="menu">
```

here the `<div id="module-in-profile">` is the id of the id for user panel list.

Comment: The PHP code you've displayed is of no relevance to the issue. I think you will need to provide code from higher up in the file ;)

Comment: Added a link to the entire file. Not sure if it is the module itself that causes this, or if there is a conflict anywhere as it works good on one of my other sites.

Comment: @Hammur this page seems abandoned. Were you able to resolve your issue? Can you post an answer?  All questions should progress to a system-recognized resolution.

Answer (score 1):

According to your answer, module "Plus User Panel" shows "User Menu", and it has not parameter to select a different menu module.

Please, check with the module developer to change or extend the module to add a parameter to select the required menu.